# http request and response forward to and from server

Tags: http, httpresponse, http-request

I am implementing HTTP server which will be responsible for:
1. Receiving requests from a browser and forwarding it to another HTTP sever.
2. And reading response from HTTP server and forwarding it directly to the browser.

In this case i am taking care of modifying only host name in the received request while sending it to HTTP server over the socket using `send()` socket API, I am using socket connection with HTTP server to forward the HTTP request received from browser.

I have following queries:

1. Will HTTP request forwarding work with `recv()` and `send()` socket APIs.
2. If `recv()` returns `0` then either server or browser has closed the socket?
   But some times my application gets stuck in receive and does not return for 1-2 mins.
3. For receiving data on socket from the server do i need to wait till `recv()` returns 0 or do i need to check content length of the received data and then continue with `recv()`.

I am very new to HTTP. 
If any one has sample application for forwarding http requests then please provide, so that i can learn it better.

Comment: You're implementing sort of a http proxy, so you can look at the source of any http proxy. [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/directory/?q=http+proxy) could be a start.

Comment: hmm... I wonder why you are trying to set up "man in the middle" software

Comment: You want to implement the entire HTTP protocol? Probably not a good idea given that you are *"very new to HTTP"*.